# Why am I getting only NaN values in all columns in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

This is how the datset_1 looks like,
[image]
But when I am making pivot table out of it as show below I am only getting `NaN` as the volues in all the columns.

```
monthly_sales_data = pd.pivot_table(dataset_1, values = "Weekly_Sales", columns = "Year", index = "Month")
monthly_sales_data = monthly_sales_data.reindex(index = ['Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
monthly_sales_data
```

I am only getting NaN values for the whole DataFrame:

[image: NaN Values of the DataFrame]

Comment: you're reindexing with values that don't exist in your index, hence the `NaN` values, your index is the month column already which is an `int`, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to sum by month and year?

Comment: You are assuming the code realizes that Month 1 = "Jan", 2 = "Feb" and so on. You are creating the indices, but pandas does not know how to handle these

Comment: `monthly_sales_data = monthly_sales_data.reindex(index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])` and what happens?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to get the values for different years based on each month's total `Weekly_Sales` values. @EdChum

Comment: After you pivot the df, you can just do `monthly_sales_data.groubpy(level=0).sum()` you can then overwrite the index values after this `monthly_sales_data.index = ['Jan','Feb','Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
monthly_sales_data = monthly_sales_data.reindex(index = ['Jan','Feb','Mar',
'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
```

to this:

```
monthly_sales_data = monthly_sales_data.reindex(index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

Comment: The problem remains the same. Only getting NaN values. I also would like to mention that, it was working properly earlier but then I made a copy of the notebook to refresh the codes and now it does not work.

Comment: @KripaluSar can you provide a sample data?

Comment: It worked after refreshing. But I can share the two different cases with you.

Comment: @KripaluSar it worked after refreshing? Feel free to share the cases if it helps.

Comment: How can I share the different results? @user5173426